# Scanner for Ubuntu sought

Tags: scanner

I need a scanner, for office work (document scanning and sending documents via email) under Ubuntu. Having no idea about scanners. What is a good recommendation these days with full Ubuntu-support?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shopping recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: So where to turn to for a good recommendation for document scanners which work with Ubuntu (as the support is so scarce)?

Comment: Ubuntu Forums, possibly. Not sure if it's on-topic there either.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the [reports from Ubuntu users](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsScanners) and [sane's list of supported devices](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-supported-devices.html).

If it's supported by sane, it should be supported by Ubuntu, as sane is the backend used for scanning.

Generally, I have good expirience with both Canon scanners and Samsung multifunction printer and scanner. Some scanners require some fiddling, others just work. If you are planning to purchase new hardware, you should probably aim for a scanner that has **Complete** support in SANE.

Comment: I just had a look to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsScannersCanon, and the most recent entry is for ubuntu 10.04, I can't recommend this link.

Comment: @pim my expirience is generally that if a scanner worked, it continues to work. Sane is rather modular... But I agree that a cross check with Sane's own list would be a good idea.

Comment: I have been using gscan2pdf (as opposed to SANE which appeared less easy to utilise) with an HP photosmart with CUPS and HPLIP without issues.  HP printer support in Ubuntu is excellent and generally very easy to set up.

Comment: @Graham gscan2pdf is a frontend for sane, so you are still using sane.